# How to create a Jquery object with containing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Forgive me if I haven't been searching in the right places, however, I've been searching all over the internet to find out how to create a jquery object, but I couldn't find a solution that fits my needs.

There is a large amount of html that must be within this object, as I plan to append the object to another element.

Example I have found:
Adding inner Html of element to a string, and adding this to jquery object:

```
var htmlText = "<div id='foo1'><a class='foo2'><h1 class='foo3'></h1></a></div>"
var $jqueryObject = $("<div>", {
                class: "bar",
                html: htmlText
        });
```

This seems to have a strange effect when appended however: When appended, the only html left on the webpage was the contents of the jquery object. So in this example, only `<div id='foo1'><a class='foo2'><h1 class='foo3'></h1></a></div>` would remain (however html, head body tags still existed)

Help is greatly appreciated...

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I then append this object to an element like so:

```
        $("#foobar").click(function() {
            $("#objectContainer").append($jqueryObject);

        });
```

Comment: What is the "strange effect"? What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: When appended, the only html left on the webpage was the contents of the jquery object. So in this example, only <div id='foo1'><a class='foo2'><h1 class='foo3'></h1></a></div> would remain (however html, head body tags still existed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var htmlText = "<div id='foo1'><a class='foo2'><h1 class='foo3'>Test</h1></a></div>";


var $jqueryObject = $("div").append(htmlText).find('.foo3').css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is correct and works, however, I wont be able to change the inner elements such as <div id='foo1'> before appending to my document, which is what I need. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @KyleBlue u can. see my answer below

Comment: Im so so confused... What you are doing must be right, however, this does not seem to work in my document... Looks like this isnt getting fixed anytime soon haha. Thanks for the help though guys

Comment: make a jsfiddle with dummy data and we can understand better :)

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the html objects in cache before appending like so:

```
$(jqueryObject).find('#foo1').css('background-color', 'grey')
```

https://jsbin.com/vuzosapedu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your page is being submitted to the server each time you click on your button.

Try

```
   $("#foobar").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#objectContainer").append($jqueryObject);

    });
```